# CSS3 animation different on chrome and others

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation

Here is in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCt32/4/) an example of the problem that I'm facing. This animation has different behavior in different browsers. I need to make all work as Chrome. Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

HTML:

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='animate'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes test {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    right: inherit;
    width: 0;
  }

  10%{ width: 100%;}

  49%{ width: 100%;}

  59% {
    left: inherit;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  100% { width: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    right: inherit;
    width: 0;
  }

  10%{ width: 100%;}

  49%{width: 100%;}

  59% {
    left: inherit;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {width: 0;}
}

.wrap{
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.animate{
  background: #000;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

  -webkit-animation: test 6s infinite;    
  animation: test 6s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Strange, if you set right to 0 initially, it will expand from the right

Comment: Really weird behavior, but you can use this solution http://jsfiddle.net/vVGmR/2/ - the only one css rule is animated here and it works. Tested on IE10, latest Firefox, Opera and Chrome

Comment: Worked for me @VasiliyGorokhov. Please, post as an answer than I can accept as the right one. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `inherit` is an invalid value for `left` and `right`, that likely isn't doing your animation any favours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution [jsfiddle.net/vVGmR/2](http://jsfiddle.net/vVGmR/2) - the only one css rule is animated here and it works. Tested on IE10, latest Firefox, Opera and Chrome

```
@keyframes test {
    0% {left: -100%;}
    10% {left: 0;}
    49% {left: 0;}
    59% {left: 100%;}
    99.99% {left: 100%;}
    100% {left: -100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0% {left: -100%;}
    10% {left: 0;}
    49% {left: 0;}
    59% {left: 100%;}
    99.99% {left: 100%;}
    100% {left: -100%;}
}
.wrap{
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.animate{
    background: #000;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: test 6s infinite;    
    animation: test 6s infinite;
}
```